# Visualization pixel with Opencv Mat at

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I don't understand why output is a strange number when I run my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat im;
    im = imread("lena.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cout << im.at<uchar>(0, 0) << endl;
    waitKey(0);
}
```

If I visualize image I see the correct image. 
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it shows the symbol, like `cout << char(123) << endl;`

You have to use int cast:

```
cout << (int) im.at<uchar>(0, 0) << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I've yet tried, but I see a very large number, not a number between 0 and 255.
I don't understand how is possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong. With your suggest I get the right value.Thank you very much.

Comment: If it helps, approve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the official [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#accessing-pixel-intensity-values) you don´t get the actual intensity value directly but a scalar.

Try this:

```
Scalar intensity = im.at<uchar>(0, 0);

cout << intensity.val[0] << endl;
```

and for images with more than one channel you can use:

```
Vec3b intensity = im.at<Vec3b>(0, 0);
cout << intensity.val[0] << intensity.val[1] << intensity.val[2] << endl;
```

Comment: With one channel it is actual intensity.

Comment: Yeah, but only with one channel and in Gray/RGB(A) Colorspace. In General it is not and this is what you have to keep in mind.

Comment: Actually, if intensity is a Vec3b, you can do this `cout << intensity << endl` and get something like `[255, 10, 22]`