# Getting pixel value in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV and I'm trying to get the pixel value from a grayscale image.

```
#include<opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(1);
    Mat image,gray_image;
    cap>>image;
    cvtColor(image,gray_image,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    std::cout<<"Value: "<<gray_image.at<uchar>(0,0);
    imshow("Window",gray_image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The pixel value is displayed as * or ~ etc. I think it is getting converted to ASCII value. How do I fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visualization pixel with Opencv Mat at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092087/visualization-pixel-with-opencv-mat-at)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to output as integer

```
std::cout<<"Value: "<<static_cast<int>(gray_image.at<uchar>(0,0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to typecast your uchar variable to int before printing

like,

```
std::cout<<"Value: "<<(int)src.at<uchar>(0,0);
```